# order by id on multi columns indexs in mysql

Tags: mysql, indexing

suppose I have a multi-column index on my table. The index is, for example, on columns a, b, and c.

Now I want to search for something like this:
select * from my_table where a=1 order by id DESC.

I'm wondering if I have to create another index like a,id in order to make my query fast or the mentioned index is enough.
I'm asking this question because I don't know how MySQL can order by id on multi-column indexes.

Comment: *how MySQL can order by id on multi-column indexes.* It can't. *if I have to create another index like a,id in order to make my query fast or the mentioned index is enough.* Depends on the rows percent selected by this query. If it is low (not above 5-7%) then index `(a,id)` may make sense.

Answer (score 1):

`INDEX(a,b,c)` is only partially useful for `WHERE a=1 ORDER BY id`.

With ENGINE=InnoDB and `id` being the `PRIMARY KEY`, `INDEX(a,b,c)` is almost identical to `INDEX(a,b,c,id)`.  But trying to use that for the query -- it stops when it sees `b`.

Think of a list of names sorted by last, first.  And the query is `... WHERE last = 'gates' ORDER BY first`.  Now imagine the list.  All the "gates's" will be there, already ordered by `first`.

The layout of that index is analogous to `INDEX(a,id)`.  (Or `INDEX(a)` with the assumption that `id` is silently tacked on.)

More on creating an optimal index, given a query:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

Oh, "DESC".  Simply start at the end -- "Gates, Zach" -- and read the list backwards until you get past the first "Gates".

To search for "Joe G." the index would be useless.  However `INDEX(first, last)` could be used.  No index of names would be very useless when searching for "J. G.".